# Python string splitlines() removes certain Unicode control characters

Tags: python, unicode

I noticed that Python's standard string method splitlines() actually removes some crucial Unicode control characters as well. Example

```
>>> s1 = u'asdf \n fdsa \x1d asdf'
>>> s1.splitlines()
[u'asdf ', u' fdsa ', u' asdf']
```

Notice how the "\x1d" character quietly disappears.

It doesn't happen if the string s1 is still a Python bytestring though (without the "u" prefix):

```
>>> s2 = 'asdf \n fdsa \x1d asdf'
>>> s2.splitlines()
['asdf ', ' fdsa \x1d asdf']
```

I can't find any information about this in the reference
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines.

Why does this happen? What other characters than "\x1d" (or unichr(29)) are affected?

I'm using Python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is indeed under-documented; I had to dig through the source code somewhat to find it.

The [`unicodetype_db.h` file](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/94f7cdab9f71/Objects/unicodetype_db.h#l3316) defines linebreaks as:

```
case 0x000A:
case 0x000B:
case 0x000C:
case 0x000D:
case 0x001C:
case 0x001D:
case 0x001E:
case 0x0085:
case 0x2028:
case 0x2029:
```

These are [generated from the Unicode database](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/94f7cdab9f71/Tools/unicode/makeunicodedata.py#l379); any codepoint listed in the Unicode standard with the `Line_Break` property set to `BK`, `CR`, `LF` or `NL` or with bidirectional category set to `B` (paragraph break) is considered a line break.

From the [Unicode Data file, version 6 of the standard](http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) lists U+001D as a paragraph break:

```
001D;<control>;Cc;0;B;;;;;N;INFORMATION SEPARATOR THREE;;;;
```

(5th column is the bidirectional category).

You could use a regular expression if you want to limit what characters to split on:

```
import re

linebreaks = re.compile(ur'[\n-\r\x85\u2028\u2929]')
linebreaks.split(yourtext)
```

would split your text on the same set of linebreaks *except* for the U+001C, U+001D or U+001E codepoints, so the three [data structuring control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#Data_structuring).