# Why is the number of lines in the file opened by the linux wc -l command and python open different?

Tags: python, file

For the machine translation corpus news-commentary-v12. When I calculate the number of lines through  `wc -l`  command, the number is 227330.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da5ZV.png)

But I open the files through python code `with open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp fp.readlines()`, the number is 227568 and 227603, respectively.

Then I open the files in binary mode `with open(filepath, 'rb')as fp`. I get 227330.
Why the number of lines in the files is different?

The corpus link : http://data.statmt.org/wmt17/translation-task/training-parallel-nc-v12.tgz

The python code. I open the files in binary mode `rb` and decode them `decode('utf-8')` I can get 227330, but in read mode `r` and only `append` I can't get the correct number.

```
en_len = 0
zh_len = 0
en = []
zh = []
with open(en_path, 'rb') as fp:
    for i in fp.readlines():
        # en.append(i)
        en.append(i.decode('utf-8').strip())
        en_len += 1
with open(zh_path, 'rb') as fp:
    for i in fp.readlines():
        # zh.append(i)
        zh.append(i.decode('utf-8').strip())
        zh_len += 1
print('en', en_len)
print('zh', zh_len)
```

Comment: Without the file in hand, and without the exact code you use to compute the number of lines, it is hard to tell. I suspect there could be some special linebreaks (such as ``\r`` of Windows) that get computed differently in ``wc`` and ``python``.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You can download the corpus at http://data.statmt.org/wmt17/translation-task/training-parallel-nc-v12.tgz and I use zh-en.

Answer (score 1):

[Unicode has more newline characters defined.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode)

The Unicode standard defines a number of characters that conforming applications should recognize as line terminators:

```
 LF:    Line Feed, U+000A
 VT:    Vertical Tab, U+000B
 FF:    Form Feed, U+000C
 CR:    Carriage Return, U+000D
 CR+LF: CR (U+000D) followed by LF (U+000A)
 NEL:   Next Line, U+0085
 LS:    Line Separator, U+2028
 PS:    Paragraph Separator, U+2029
```

`wc` only counts the LF characters.

Edit: actually, the python `readlines()` method splits on even more characters, as shown in [this excellent answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24453934/2354344) Also included are:

```
FS: File Separator U+001C
GS: Group Separator U+001D
RS: Record Separator U+001E
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also consider the LF characters. But I use notepad++ to open the file and LF as newline characters, I can't get 227330.

Comment: Thanks. I think there are a few other characters in some sentences.